# How to load Triggers to Teradata Server using bteq

Tags: oracle, migration, database-migration, teradata

We're migrating database from Oracle to Teradata.

We have `.sql` files with valid trigger DDL and `.bteq` files with `.compile` commands for these triggers. But when we run these `.bteq` files we get errors and trigger is not loaded.
For example, file `td_instrg1.sql` contains trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TD_INSTRG1
AFTER INSERT
ON TD_EMPLOYEES
REFERENCING NEW AS X1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(X1.id is not null)
BEGIN ATOMIC
   (INSERT INTO TD_EMPLOYEES1     VALUES(X1.id, X1.name, X1.monthly_income);)
END;
```

and file td_instrg1.bteq contains the following commands:

```
.logon vmdbsrv016/dbc, dbc;

DATABASE twm;

.compile FILE=td_instrg1.sql;

.logoff;
```

Please advise how to load triggers from scripts using `bteq` utility.

Comment: It isn't valid DDL for an Oracle trigger; is it for Teradata? It might help someone who knows more about it than I do if you show the errors you get.

Comment: The syntax is valid, as I loaded this trigger directly from bteq and Teradata SQL Assistant. The thing is that we need to load it from file

Comment: here is the error message Errors reported during compilation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SPL1027:E(L25), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(7947):Only create/replace p

Comment: Please add that to the question, it doesn't work as a comment. From the bit I can see it seems to support what @RobPaller said in his answer; if what he has suggested doesn't fix the problem you should comment on that saying why, and if you tried it and still got an error then show the file and the new error message in your question too. (I know nothing about Teradata!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.COMPILE` command in BTEQ is reserved for the compilation of Teradata stored procedures. Your DDL statements for the triggers can be executed directly. If you have separate files containing the DDL you can reference them from within BTEQ using the `.RUN` command:

```
.logon vmdbsrv016/dbc, {password};

DATABASE twm;

.RUN FILE=td_instrg1.sql;

.logoff;
```

Comment: Rob, thank you very much!!!! It looks like it really works with .RUN command. Great thanks!